# How to access a model from view without using the foreach loop

Tags: laravel, view, model, eloquent

I was trying to create a view where I can access the data one by one like I have a model of questions and want to show each question on a separate page or at least I want to have the control how each question should look on the same page.

in my controller I m doing something like this

```
public funciton ShowQuestion($testID){
   $questions = QuestionS::find($testID); 
   // now I have all the questions of a particular test I provided using $testid
   return view('pages.showQuestion')->with('questions' , $questions) ; 
}
```

In the showQuestion view I want something, using which I can access each instance(row) of the table individually.

Comment: Can you share us your code in `showQuestion` view?

Comment: find() return a single object .. doesn't need a loop ..

Comment: @Demonyowh. But there are multiple questions with a single testID, as it is many to one relationship between questions and tests!

Comment: @aceraven777 `@extend('layout.app') ;`

`<div class = "container" >`

 `@foreach($questions as question) `
  `<h3> {{$question->statement}} </h3> `
  `@foreach($questions->choices as $choice)  <!-- Each Question contains mulitple choices -->`
   `<h5> {{$choice->text}} </h5>`
  `@endforeach`
 `@endforeach`            But I want something with more flexibility over each individual object of question

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to question ID not to testID,

Try this:

```
    public function ShowQuestion($id){
   $question = Question::find($id); 
   //now you should get particular question with given ID
   return view('pages.showQuestion')->with('question' , $question) ; 
}
```

Comment: But I m not looking for a single question. I want to get all the questions in test and then want to manipulate them individually.

Comment: you can try to run this Controller under a button, so grab all questions and refer to one with a button without returning a view